# How to set joins in Eloquent as default for each query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an existing database with a rather bad architecture which I cant change. I want to use it via Eloquent. While using this database I need to add couple of joints to all queries, something like this:

```
<?php
class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $table      = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'index';
    public    $timestamps = FALSE;

    function __construct($attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->leftJoin('sites', 'sites.Siteindex', '=', 'users.index');

        $this->leftJoin(DB::raw('(`lookups` `l`)'), function($join){
            $join->on('l.value', '=', 'users.type')->where('l.fieldname', '=', 'user_type');
        });
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What is the relationship type between those two tables?

Comment: @phaberest there are no real relationship, just bunch of joints.

Comment: You could try to use `hasOne()`and `belongsTo()` anyway, but you'll need to have two models, one for each. In `User` model use a method called `sites` and inside of it `return $this->hasOne('Site', 'sites', 'Siteindex');`, in `Site` model do the same in reverse but having `return $this->belogsTo('User', 'users', 'index');` inside a `users` method.

Comment: @phaberest yes, but problem is that there is a lot of joins...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a __construct function in the User Model, create a scope.

```
public function scopeGetSiteIndex($query) {
    return $query->leftJoin('sites', 'sites.Siteindex', '=', 'users.index');
}
```

Then you can call it from the controller

```
$siteIndex = User::getSiteIndex()->get();
```

Comment: When using `joins`, remember to use `select` too, otherwise joined table's `id` will override main table's `id` and you will experience unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I had the same problem with paginate.  I fixed it by reverting from Laravel 4.2.11 to 4.2.0.  It must be a bug.

Comment: did you reported about this?